# Array of references coming null in RNFirebase

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

From firestore collection of document with field of type ***array of references*** is giving ***array of null*** when doing get on that collection in react-native-firebase. Where as in **adminSDK** and **firestore npm package**, the data is coming perfectly.
Can any one tell what is the reason behind it. Also document having field of type reference is coming right in react-native-firebase

Expected Response

```
active: true,
instruments: [
    firestore.googleapis.com/project/xxxx-xxxxx/database/(default)/documents/Companies/demo/instrumentGroup/bznCmbtSzdVFdPrbAexv,
    firestore.googleapis.com/project/xxxx-xxxxx/database/(default)/documents/Companies/demo/instrumentGroup/xKMvoovwWKPc5xxjsc1K,
    firestore.googleapis.com/project/xxxx-xxxxx/database/(default)/documents/Companies/demo/instrumentGroup/FsLiNcJIyn78JTOcna4H
],
name:"Chamfer",
type:"Range",
unit:"mm"
```

Actual Response

```
active: true,
instruments: [
    null,
    null,
    null
],
name:"Chamfer",
type:"Range",
unit:"mm"
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the Android SDK itself: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/bk3oX1RIleU

It should be fixed if you bump to version 11.6.0 of the native SDKs.